# Diasble button animation or effects xamarin-forms

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, windows-10-universal

I have a touch screen to start page, and would just want to navigate to the next page when tapped - no animations/color changing effects on hover, clicked/pressed. But there's a gray opaque box when clicked... Anyone know how to override it?

P.S.
I know there are more ways to do this but I decided to create the whole page as a button and reduced the opacity to almost transparent.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to remove the `Button`'s template:

```xml
<Button Template="{x:Null}">
    ... your content
</Button>
```

Alternatively you can create a `Button` style, with just `ContentPresenter` in its template:

```xml
<Style x:Key="InvisibleButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And you can reuse this style on multiple places.

Comment: I forgot to add that I'm using Xamarin.Forms, this only works in UWP i think?