# Xamarin.Forms - disable button animation UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am writing an Xamarin Forms application and I have a transparent button over some other stuff so it is all clickable. But when I hover over the button or click it in UWP I get some grey animations.

The Problem is already described here: [Diasble button animation or effects xamarin-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724545/diasble-button-animation-or-effects-xamarin-forms)

But there is no solution that works for me.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63850/android-button-how-to-make-transparent-background-and-no-border does this help?

Comment: No, I already have the transparent button, but when it is pressed, there is a grey animation, that is described in the link I posted.

Comment: Yes, the link you posted states it's for UWP, and you're using xamarin.forms

Comment: as stated by the comment `I forgot to add that I'm using Xamarin.Forms, this only works in UWP i think?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem with UWP is, that all controls will follow the Styles that are supplied with the UWP framework.

In this case we are talking about the Button style and the actual implementation can be found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299109.aspx

So if you want to disable certain features of a Button, you'll need to supply your own UWP style.

Easiest way to do this, is to just copy / paste the XAML style code from the website into your App.Xaml in the UWP project of your Xamarin forms solution.
After that, seeing your request, just delete the `<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">` and `<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">` regions.
That way there won't be any animation on OnHover or OnPressed.

So the final style would be like:

```
   <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```